# how do I send control characters to serial device

Tags: remote, serial-port, execute-command

I have a serial device, which needs to receive the commands ctrl+W and ctrl+V
before I can begin programming it. I was trying to use cutecom, but I don't see an option to send control characters.

verbatim, what the instructions say is:

(decimal 23),  (decimal 22)

where <> are being used in place of quotes.

Comment: If there's a button or pulldown for hex input somewhere check that and enter the 0x1716.  You mighnt also need 0A0D at the end of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to `echo -e` symbols to /dev/ttyUSB0 or other device.

Example:

```
echo -e "\027\026" > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

026 and 027 egual decimal 22 and 23.

But your user needs to be in `dialout` group. Or use `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `minicom`. Complete user guide you have [here](http://www.shop.ngxtechnologies.com/download/jtag/minicom_User_Guide.pdf)